# App crashes when I try to start a new activity if a user has already authenticated with Firebase with google.

Tags: java, android, firebase

My app runs fine when I test it on an Android device but once the user logs in it crashes instantly and crashes on start up unless I do a clean install of the apk. I'm authenticating users with google sign in with Firebase. The authentication is working fine as users are being registered with my associated Firebase account but I intended for the users to be directed to the Auth activity from my log in activity if they had already logged in but instead I'm experiencing the above issue.

`

```
package com.test.firebase;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;






public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SignInButton button;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Auth.class));
            }
        }
    };
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}



private void signIn(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Auth went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    }

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {

                        Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
}

}
```

`
I'd appreciate any help I can get with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just use this method directly on Onstart it will check if users already exist or not if it does you can simply start other activity.
Just check simply if users are not logged in and somehow you find your self in other activity, just add the else statement to redirect you to first activity!

You Should have pasted the error you got, I can somehow help you more with that in-hand.

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
```